# Increase and decrease horizontal overline and the vertical distance

Tags: math-mode, macros, amsmath, packages, fractions

If I have this MWE,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document} 
\[\overline{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}\]
\end{document}
```

it is possible increase (without to use a rule-macro) the lenght of `\overline` and the vertical distance like the image below?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, `\Xoverline` pads the content vertically by `\Xgap` and the overline gets extended by `\Xtend`.  Note: the vertical padding is applied to top and bottom of argument...this could be problematic if you wish to apply a subscript *outside* of the `\Xoverline`.  If so, let me know, and I will attempt to address.

In the MWE, 2pt are added as vertical gap, and the overline length is shrunk by 2pt.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stackengine,scalerel}
\newlength\Xgap
\newlength\Xtend
\setlength\Xgap{2pt}
\setlength\Xtend{-2pt}
\newcommand\Xoverline[1]{%
  \overline{\ThisStyle{\kern\Xtend
  \ensurestackMath{\addstackgap[\Xgap]{\SavedStyle#1}}
  \kern\Xtend}}}
\begin{document} 
\[
\overline{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}\,
\Xoverline{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is perfect also because I have understood almost the macro :-)! Hence is it necessary always to make a macro? My best regards?